# Only some word need to be in hyperlink in php word

Tags: php

Hi i'm using  php word to make a document i want some word in hyperlink like this[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg61b.png) but my  whole word in a line like this [hyperlink-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGYnu.png)
 is there any way to remove hyperlink from some words

```
$section->addLink($data[$j]['ArticleURL'], cleanstring($data[$j]['publicationPrint']).  
' | ' . formatDateForEmail($data[$k]['previewDate']) .  
" | " . $editionprint, $linkFontStyleName, $fontStyleIndexPara);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can use :

```
$section->addLink($data[$j]['ArticleURL'], cleanstring($data[$j]['publicationPrint']);

$runs = array();
$runs[] = $section;
$runs[] = array('text' => ' | '. formatDateForEmail($data[$k]['previewDate']));
....

$docx->addText($runs);
```

Look the example at the end of this page : https://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/word-content/insert-link-Word-document-with-PHP

For now, you put all your text inside the `addLink` method, it seems normal all your text is a link.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addText() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\report edite\sreport_new_I0027.php:583 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown  it gives this error

Comment: Thanks Vincent but we are using php word and you are suggestion a method of php docx. i guess two plugins are not good for using.